# Regex for putting comma before city name in address

Tags: regex

Generally address comes with comma seperationa and can be splitted using simple regex. e.g

```
123 Main St, Los Angeles, CA, 90210
```

We can apply regex here and split using comma. But in my database addresses are stored without comma. e.g

```
A Better Property Management<br/> 6621 E PACIFIC COAST HWY<br/> STE 255<br/> LONG BEACH CA 90803-4241
```

And I want to put comma before the city. Something like this:

```
A Better Property Management<br/> 6621 E PACIFIC COAST HWY<br/> STE 255<br/> LONG BEACH ,CA 90803-4241
```

I was thing about finding the last two letter word from the end and put comma using regex . But I also need to account for the situations where we don't have complete address or missing city and pincodes. Is there a way this can be done. I only found solutions where we can split using comma but not the reverse.

I was thinking if we could select the last 2 words before numbers with something like `[A-Za-z]{2}` (don't know if this is correct). And at the same time if we can check to do this only if the string ends with numbers.

I tried

```
(\b(AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FM|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MH|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VI|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY|Alabama|Alaska|Arizona|Arkansas|California|Colorado|Connecticut|Delaware|District of Columbia|Florida|Georgia|Hawaii|Idaho|Illinois|Indiana|Iowa|Kansas|Kentucky|Louisiana|Maine|Maryland|Massachusetts|Michigan|Minnesota|Mississippi|Missouri|Montana|Nebraska|Nevada|New Hampshire|New Jersey|New Mexico|New York|North Carolina|North Dakota|Ohio|Oklahoma|Oregon|Pennsylvania|Rhode Island|South Carolina|South Dakota|Tennessee|Texas|Utah|Vermont|Virginia|Washington|West Virginia|Wisconsin|Wyoming)\b)
```

https://regex101.com/r/75fqO6/1

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and tell how us that worked, and then show us the cases that your code doesn't work on.

Comment: RegExp is not the silver bullet for data quality remediation that you seem to think it is, especially in the context of severely unstructured data as you've got here. Depending on the language your broader program leverages, I would propose the use of a more advanced Natural Language Processing library like [`libpostal`](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal) to try and get a more "informed" view on the components of an address string and re-combine with the delimiters you desire.

Comment: @esqew yes sure , I will look into libpostal. But looking for a solution which could work without any external library

Comment: @Duck_dragon Can you elaborate on the (seemingly arbitrary) requirement to not use any external library? There are thousands upon thousands of rules that you would have to codify just for US addresses, and thousands more when international addresses come into the fold (and even then you would still run into odd, yet valid, edge cases). Why try to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @esqew Yes I understand. I was thinking if we could select the last 2 words before numbers with something like this `[A-Za-z]{2}` ( don't know if this is correct). And at the same time if we can check to do this only if the string ends with numbers. And not validating adresses

Comment: Please add your efforts to the question itself, it is very important.

Comment: From your last comment, it appears you want to use `[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d(?:[\d-]*\d)?$` and replace with `,$0`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Peyzli/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes this works perfectly. I tried this https://regex101.com/r/75fqO6/1 . but your seems much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d(?:[\d-]*\d)?$
```

Replace with `,$0`.
See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Peyzli/1). *Details*:

- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?:[\d-]*\d)?` - an optional substring of zero or more digits/hyphens and then a digit
- `$` - end of string.

The `$0` in the replacement is a backreference to the whole match value, all text matched by the regex is put back where it was found with a prepended comma.

Comment: the address can sometimes end with `UT 84042-1229<br/>` . Si I included `<[^>]*` this in your regex but I want to make it optional

Comment: @Duck_dragon You mean `[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d(?:[\d-]*\d)?(?:<[^>]*>)?$`?

Comment: yes I did something similar to this `[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d(?:[\d-]*\d)+(<[^>]*>)?$`